# Dynamically require multiple files using Webpack's DefinePlugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have an array of file names that I want to import. The file names are computed at build time. If I have a single file name, I can do:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  component_file: '"path/Component"',
})
```

Then in the source:

```
require(component_file);
```

This includes `path/Component` in the build, as expected.

However, if I try the following, it doesn't work.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  component_files: ['"path/Component"', '"path/Component2"'],
})
```

Then in the source:

```
// component_files is converted object by Webpack.
Object.keys(component_files).forEach(file => require(file));
```

This causes an error `Cannot find module '0'`. This makes sense because Webpack just does static analysis, it can't process `require`s with variables as the argument. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use DefinePlugin to define dependencies that are then required within your application, you could include them as entries within your config so that they are included at compile time:

```
{
  entry: [
    ...component_files,
    'app.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'll try it later, but wouldn't that create separate bundles? I want all the dependencies in one modules.

Comment: No it would bundle `component_files` and `'app.js`' to a single file which will export `'app.js'`. You may get some other bundles for split chunks as per your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving dynamic bundling by environment variables, you have to wrap `require` statements inside conditional blocks that will be determined as "dead code" or not.
Then, on build time, these dead `require` statement will be removed, which will result exclusion from the final bundle.

The predicate of each conditional block must be evaluated as a boolean value on build time. This can happen only if the predicate is a plain comparison between 2 primitive values or a pure boolean. For example:

```js
// webpack.config.json
new DefinePlugin({
  "process.env.component_a": "true",
  "process.env.component_b": "false",
  "process.env.component_c": "'true'",
})

// in application:
if (process.env.component_a) {
  const a = require('./a') // will be included
}
if (process.env.component_b) {
  const b = require('./b') // will be excluded
}

if (process.env.component_c === "true") {
  const c = require('./c') // will be included
}
```

**Important Note**
Leaving the value undefined is not good enough for excluding a module from the final bundle.

```js
/* THE WRONG WAY */

// webpack.config.json
new DefinePlugin({
  "process.env.component_a": "true",

})

// in application:
if (process.env.component_a) {
  const a = require('./a') // will be included
}
if (process.env.component_b) {
  // even though this block is unreachable, b will be included in the bundle!
  const b = require('./b') 
}
```